# How do I get an RSS feed of my friends in Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus, rss

I want to follow my friends on Google+ with an RSS reader.

Is there any means for obtaining all of their RSS feeds all at once via Google+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shameless plug.

You could try [BazQux Reader](http://bazqux.com), it directly supports reading of Google Plus pages. You only need to enter G+ page URL in "Add subscription" dialog to subscribe and read it like ordinary blog.

Comment: it is free trial ... is there any free unlimited other app there?